# C++: Debug Assertion Failed (using OpenCV library)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code:

```
int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 256;
int S_MIN = 0;
int S_MAX = 256;
int V_MIN = 0;
int V_MAX = 256;

const int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;

const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS = 50;

const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20 * 20;
const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH / 1.5;

const string windowName = "Original Image";
const string windowName1 = "HSV Image";
const string windowName2 = "Thresholded Image";
const string windowName3 = "After Morphological Operations";
const string trackbarWindowName = "Trackbars";
void on_trackbar(int, void*)
{


}
string intToString(int number) {


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
void createTrackbars() {


    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName, 0);
    char TrackbarName[50];
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "H_MIN", H_MIN);
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "H_MAX", H_MAX);
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "S_MIN", S_MIN);
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "S_MAX", S_MAX);
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "V_MIN", V_MIN);
    sprintf(TrackbarName, "V_MAX", V_MAX); 
    createTrackbar("H_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &H_MIN, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("H_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &H_MAX, H_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &S_MIN, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("S_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &S_MAX, S_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &V_MIN, V_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("V_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &V_MAX, V_MAX, on_trackbar);
}
void drawObject(int x, int y, Mat &frame) {

    circle(frame, Point(x, y), 20, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (y - 25>0)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, y - 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (y + 25<FRAME_HEIGHT)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, y + 25), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x, FRAME_HEIGHT), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (x - 25>0)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x - 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(0, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    if (x + 25<FRAME_WIDTH)
        line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(x + 25, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    else line(frame, Point(x, y), Point(FRAME_WIDTH, y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    putText(frame, intToString(x) + "," + intToString(y), Point(x, y + 30), 1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

}
void morphOps(Mat &thresh) {

    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3));
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8, 8));
    erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);
    erode(thresh, thresh, erodeElement);
    dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);
    dilate(thresh, thresh, dilateElement);
}
void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed) {
    Mat temp;
    threshold.copyTo(temp);

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    double refArea = 0;
    bool objectFound = false;
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
        int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
        if (numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS) {
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

                Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                double area = moment.m00;
                if (area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area<MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area>refArea) {
                    x = moment.m10 / area;
                    y = moment.m01 / area;
                    objectFound = true;
                    refArea = area;
                }
                else objectFound = false;

            }
            //let user know you found an object
            if (objectFound == true) {
                putText(cameraFeed, "Tracking Object", Point(0, 50), 2, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                drawObject(x, y, cameraFeed);
            }

        }
        else putText(cameraFeed, "TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER", Point(0, 50), 1, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        bool trackObjects = true;
    bool useMorphOps = false;
    Mat cameraFeed;
    Mat HSV;
    Mat threshold;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    createTrackbars();
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(0);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    while (1) {
        capture.read(cameraFeed);
        cvtColor(cameraFeed, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), threshold);
        if (useMorphOps)
            morphOps(threshold);
        if (trackObjects)
            trackFilteredObject(x, y, threshold, cameraFeed);
        imshow(windowName2, threshold);
        imshow(windowName, cameraFeed);
        imshow(windowName1, HSV);
        waitKey(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever i run it in debug mode, i get the following error:
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: __acrt_first_block == header

I have to say that it only happens when the boolean variable trackObjects in the main function is equal to true (when it's set to false the program works great).

Setting it to true "activates" this part of the code in the main function:

```
    if (trackObjects)
        trackFilteredObject(x, y, threshold, cameraFeed);
```

which might be causing the problem.

Any idea on how i can fix this?
Thanks!